# How to check and get session value on view file in zend framework 2

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I am working in zend framework 2.I want to know in view file and layout file [.phtml] how can I access session data.

I am accessing session in controller like below:

```
$session = new \Zend\Session\Container('identity');
```

But I want to access this session on view file. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass data to your view inside your controller.
Check [the documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#controllers-and-view-models) for examples:

```
$view = new ViewModel(array(
    'identity' => $identity,
));
```

Comment: Thanks wilt,I know this solution.But I just wanted to alternate solution to access session data on view file. Any way I have find ,using view helper it can be access

Comment: @Khushboo care to share the solution here?